# Set Java systemProperties for all Java Processes

Tags: java, default-value, system-properties

I have a system Property (JVM Provided) called 
`networkaddress.cache.ttl`. This setting has a bad default of `-1` and should be set to a different value (e.g.: 60).

I know that this can be set by calling `java -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -jar main.jar`

Is there a way to set this value as a system-wide default, such that any process running `java -jar main.jar` would pick it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

You can set it to add JVM options to all Java processes.

In your case it should be set to

```
-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=60
```

JVM process should output at the beginning:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: <your value>
```

If they pick your setting.

edit: alex

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperties().get("foobar"));
  }
}
```

Test:

```
$ export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfoobar=1'
$ java Main
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfoobar=1 
1
```